# Too easy to rotate map when zoom

Tags: rotation, zooming, mapbox, gesture, mapbox-ios

When I use 2 fingers to zoom map, more times is fired the rotation gestures. How can I prevent this behavior?
In Android, for example, we have this method

```
mapboxMap.getUiSettings().setIncreaseRotateThresholdWhenScaling(true);
```

that helps to prevent rotation while zooming, but in iOS I don't find this.